# How to transform the data and calculate the TFIDF value?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

My data format is：
`datas = {[1,2,4,6,7],[2,3],[5,6,8,3,5],[2],[93,23,4,5,11,3,5,2],...}`
Each element in datas is a sentence ,and each number is a word.I want to get the TFIDF value for each number. How to do it with sklearn or other ways?

My code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer  
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
datas = {[1,2,4,6,7],[2,3],[5,6,8,3,5],[2],[93,23,4,5,11,3,5,2]}
vectorizer=CountVectorizer()

transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(vectorizer.fit_transform(datas))  
print(tfidf)
```

My code doesn't work.Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/zhuowei/Desktop/OpenNE-master/OpenNE-
master/src/openne/buildTree.py", line 103, in <module>
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(datas)   File
"C:\Users\zhuowei\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 869, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)   File "C:\Users\zhuowei\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):   File 
"C:\Users\zhuowei\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)   File 
"C:\Users\zhuowei\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 232, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower()) 
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: What did you search for in order to solve this, and what did you find? What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have put my code above

Comment: Thanks for the code. Please include the full traceback still, though.

Comment: ok I have add the full traceback, I think my way is wrong ,but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't look like a full traceback.  Also `str(nodes[0])` in the traceback doesn't seem to correspond to anything in your question. You should probably review the guidance for how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Having curly brackets `{}` makes `datas` as a `dict` but the inner elements are `lists` which will give error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `CountVectorizer` which requires an iterable of strings. Something like:

```
datas = ['First sentence', 
         'Second sentence', ...
          ...
         'Yet another sentence']
```

But your data is a list of lists, which is why the error occurs. You need to make the inner lists as strings for the CountVectorizer to work. You can do this:

```
datas = [' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in datas]
```

This will result in `datas` like this:

```
['1 2 4 6 7', '2 3', '5 6 8 3 5', '2', '93 23 4 5 11 3 5 2']
```

Now this form is consumable by `CountVectorizer`. But even then you will not get proper results, because of the default [`token_pattern` in CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

> **token_pattern** : ’(?u)\b\w\w+\b’
>
> string Regular expression denoting what constitutes a
>   “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp select
>   tokens of **2 or more alphanumeric characters** (punctuation is completely
>   ignored and always treated as a token separator)

In order for it to consider your numbers as words, you will need to change it so that it can accept single letters as words by doing this:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b")
```

Then it should work. But now your numbers are changed into strings